# jQuery colorbox class name is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am unable to find what i am doing wrong

I am using jQuery colorbox

```
<a title="Add Externaal attendee" class ="addmeetingroom" href="http://webfaction/UI/user/attandee.php" style="background-color:orange;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;"> Add Attendee<a>
```

here is the script for colorbox

```
    <script>
    function getLBTitle(that){
         title= $(that).data("title");
         if(typeof title == 'undefined'){
                title = $(that).attr("original-title")
         }
         if(typeof title == 'undefined'){
                title = $(that).attr("title")
         }
         return title;
         }
    $(".addmeetingroom").colorbox({width: "600", initialWidth: "500", height:"500", top:"5%",title:function(){return getLBTitle($(this));}});
</script>
```

I don't know why i am getting

```
TypeError: $(".addmeetingroom").colorbox is not a function
```

Comment: Did you load the plugin?

Comment: yeah boss it is already ther my js view is showing all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure the colorbox plugin is loaded

2) Wrap your code in the $.ready function so it is executed when the dom is loaded:

```
$(function(){
    $(".addmeetingroom").colorbox({wid...
});
```

Comment: what a pathetic situation i tried this one also but still same

Comment: There must be something wrong with the way you're loading the plugin. Do you load the plugin *after* jQuery?